# FileInputStream not throwing FileNotFoundException as documented?

Tags: java, java-io

The constructor `FileInputStream(String name)` of the `java.io.FileInputStream` class declares that it throws a `FileNotFoundException`, and it states in its javadoc:

> If the named file **does not exist**, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading then a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

However, invoking it with a name of a non-existent file doesn't cause any exceptions to be thrown:

```
@Test(expected = FileNotFoundException.class)
public void nonExistentFileThrowsFileNotFoundException() throws FileNotFoundException {
    new FileInputStream("this file totally doesnt exist");
}
```

This test fails - no exceptions are thrown. Looking at the code of the constructor, it is clear that no exceptions should be thrown - it is merely invoking the `java.io.File` constructor:

```
public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);
}
```

Is this a design/documentation flaw? In my view, the `FileInputStream` constructor should neither declare a `throws FileNotFoundException`, nor should its javadoc state that it throws. What gives?

Comment: The test runs succesfully with me.

Comment: Fun fact: if I use the name `"this file totally doesn't exist"` (with an apostrophe), it does throw the exception, but I suppose that's because the apostrophe is not allowed inside the file name

Comment: @ZouZou which version of Java are you using? I'm using Oracle JDK 8 u 31.

Comment: Which version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: I'm also using JUnit 4.11 with Java 8 (though I guess the Java version is not a problem). It's weird, I just created a new test file with only this test and I have no errors. Do you get this exception with a standard program? (just to be sure if the problem is with JUnit or not).

Comment: " it is clear that no exceptions should be thrown" - have you looked to *public FileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException* (this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);)? Last command is *open(name);* - it throws *FileNotFoundException*.

Comment: @agad thanks, I missed the `this` part, i.e. that it was actually invoking another constructor. It pointed me in the right direction. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

**PEBKAC**

So yeah, this happened:
[image: "this file totally doesnt exist" file exists]

I had the same test for `FileOutputStream`, which must have created the file - which is why this test actually found the file. `FileOutputStream` in turn doesn't throw an exception for non-existent files, so that test was pointless. I'm so embarrassed. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here, when you could just as easily post the text. Waste of bandwidth, reduced legibility, nothing to recommend it whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP It's not a picture of text, it's a picture of a portion of my directory tree. The picture was supposed to show a portion of my IntelliJ window to indicate that the file was actually created in my project directory. It tells more than the text on it alone.

Comment: It is copy-pasteable as text. Do that. It's my nickel and I'm not paying for your pictures.

Comment: With all due respect, I still disagree that copying and pasting the text would convey the same information. I am leaving the picture :)